# getting array in an array values with conditions

Tags: powershell, office365

I am trying to filter the messages property of

```
(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $token -Method Get).Value
```

It seems like the strings are array within an array since the result of

```
$Messages.messages | ft
```

is something like this

> MessageText   : A post-incident report has been published.
>
> PublishedTime : 2020-10-05T18:58:01.69Z
>
> MessageText   : A post-incident report has been published.
>
> PublishedTime : 2020-10-09T12:19:00.1Z

My goal is to display all MessageText that happened after the date, which will I declare in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but this should work for you

```
$filterDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) #Messages from the last week
$Messages = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $token -Method Get).Value
($Messages.messages | Where-Object {$_.PublishedTime -ge $filterDate}).MessageText
```

I assumed that your invoke-restmethod call was saved in the $Messages variable.

Comment: thanks. I trying to figure out now how to convert the $filterdate to match the format of publishedtime.

Comment: This might help you with that: https://blog.itpro.tv/get-date-powershell-cmdlet/